# Reset pendingMocks on nock scope

Tags: node.js, testing, nock

I'm trying to run multiple assertions against a nock scope and mock the requests in a beforeEach, however I'm seeing `scope.pendingMocks()` with requests even after I've cleaned all with:

```
  afterEach(() => {
    nock.cleanAll();
  });
```

What's the best way to set up mocks on the same host with multiple requests and assert requests freshly in each test?